# Why Faker does not return Datetime Object?

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I am doing Laravel Testing and when I use faker->datetime() or faker->dateTime($max = 'now') for created and updated at but it always give me this error?

Error Message '2017-03-29 14:21:48' does not match expected type "object".

```
'created_at' => $faker->dateTime($max = 'now'),
'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime($max = 'now')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In faker `dateTime()` returns a timestamp.  Laravel uses `Carbon` under the hood for the timestamps.  You can create a Carbon instance from your Faker timestamp:

```
'created_at' => new Carbon($faker->dateTime($max = 'now')),
'updated_at' => new Carbon($faker->dateTime($max = 'now'))
```